# Rotate display or touch-screen without X

Tags: display, input, chrome-os, chromium-os

My Samsung Galaxy Book 10.6" has an issue on Linux based OSes (Ubuntu 17,18,19, Debian and ChromiumOS) where the digitizer (touch screen input) does not match the display - tapping the top right corner will trigger an action on the bottom left, for example.

On regular Linux distros (such as Ubuntu where I did most of the troubleshooting) this is fairly easy to fix as I can use xinput to change the rotation matrix of the digitizer, but I am using ChromiumOS which does not use X (it uses freon instead)

I've tried adding `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="fbcon=rotate:1"` to my startup parameters but that doesn't seem to have any effect on any of the OSes I've tried.

Comment: Is a  digitizer a touch screen?

Comment: Please clarify your post with a specific technical question. What else have you tried for 'freon' and other systems? Exactly which OSes have you used, surely not 'every Linux based OS' available.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor A digitizer is the touch element of a touchscreen.

Comment: @0xSheepdog I tried various versions of Ubuntu (17, 18 and 19) as well as Debian and Android, all of which had the issue. Windows 10 does not have this problem. If it's any help, the display defaults itself to portrait on Linux based OSes (the ones I tried anyway) and landscape on Windows, which is how it's meant to be.

I would try another display server on chromeOS if I could, but that's not possible unfortunately.

Comment: Trouble with the word digitizer, is it has too many meanings.

Comment: I just mean the part of the display that is touched and is used as an input, rather than the visual output part.